# How to display drop-down lists after pressing the button?

Tags: reactjs

I need to display dropdown list after click on the button "Обучить".

For example, user puts the sentence 'i need* help' in the textfield, i need to render dropdown list with words related to the word with * in the end after clicking the button. (the words i get from backend after sending the word to the server i get the list in json format).

So I somehow need to parse the sentence or maybe you know more stable approach to this task.

I tried parsing, it is not very stable and was't working for me too good.

The code of the component with my parsing try is here:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // initial state
    this.state = {
        textInput: ''
    }

}

clear = () => {
    // return the state to initial
    this.setState({
        textInput: ''
    })
}

changeHandler = (event) => {
    let textInput = event.target.value;
    if(textInput !== ''){
        let tempArray = textInput.split(" ");// `convert string into array`
        let filterArray = tempArray.filter(word => word.endsWith('*'));
        this.setState({textInput, filterArray});
    }
}


render(){
    return (
        <Paper style={{maxWidth: 936, marginLeft: '250px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
            <AppBar position="static" color="default" elevation={0}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Grid container spacing={16} alignItems="center">
                        <Grid item xs>
                            <TextField
                                fullWidth
                                placeholder="Введите фразу которую нужно обучить"
                                id = 'textInput'
                                InputProps={{
                                    disableUnderline: true,
                                }}
                                value={this.state.textInput}
                                onChange={(e)=>{this.changeHandler(e)}}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68 90%)'}}>
                                Обучить
                            </Button>
                            <Tooltip title="Сбросить">
                                <IconButton>
                                    <RefreshIcon color="inherit" style={{display: 'block'}} id = 'clearButton' onClick={this.clear}/>
                                </IconButton>
                            </Tooltip>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <div style={{margin: '40px 16px'}}>
                <Typography color="textSecondary" align="center">
                    Пока ничего не было обучено
                </Typography>
            </div>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

I need you to help me put up stable approach to this task.

I need to see that the word is found and dropdown list is rendered, you can just put up the local variable that has some words that should be displayed in the list when we found the word with *.

Comment: What you mean by "and was't working for me too good"? (btw I can see the drop down part in your code, please be more specific about your problem.)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani The problem is that I don’t understand how to realize this case, I am almost new to react and I don’t understand how to find word like this in the input and how to display component on click, component of the list is not written, I am asking for help to do this task, you can do it any way that you want

Comment: Check this link for edited code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5c61qs?embed=1&file=index.js